# construction of step functions to show integrability using Beppo Levi's theorem

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, step-function

Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be measurable, $f\colon M\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous, bounded. Claim: $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable.

I was able to prove it for $M$ additionally bounded. How to reduce the arbitrary case to $M$ bounded?

**edit**: With $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ measurable we mean that the characteristic function of $M$ is Lebesgue integrable

My attempt: Since $f$ is continuous and bounded, $f(A)$ is bounded, so that $f(A)\subset [a,b]$. Now I don't know how to chose a suitable partition of $[a,b]$ to define step functions such that I can apply Beppo Levi's monotone convergence theorem for Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is open in $\mathbb R$ then  $f^{-1}(U)$ is open $M$ which means there is an open set $V$ in $\mathbb R^{n}$ such that $f^{-1}(U)=M\cap V$. This makes $f^{-1}(U)$ a measurable set. Hence $f$ is measurable. Integrability is not true in general. If $M=\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=\frac 1 {1+|x|}$ then $f$ is not integrable.

If $M$ has finite Lebesgue measure and $f$ is bounded by $C$ then $\int|f| \leq C\lambda (M) <\infty$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, so $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Does it mean that the claim is only true if $M\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$ or when does it fail?

Comment: @hetty It fails if $M$ is not bounded.

Comment: uh okay, thank you.

Comment: oh, but with $M$ measurable we mean that $\int1_Mdx<\infty$, where $1_M$ is the characteristic function of $M$. I wasn't aware of that with "measurable"  can mean different things (we haven't really learned measure theory  )

Comment: @hetty Sorry for this comment, but isn't it strange that you are asking about Lebesgue integrability of a function when you haven't learned measure theory?  I haven't seen anyone using your definition of  a measurable set.

Comment: Murthy sorry because of this and thank you for asking. We have introduced measurable sets as above, defined Null sets where the integral of the characteristic function vanishes, and we have defined Lebesgue integrability to be the $L^1$-limit of step functions. But we haven't learned about $\sigma$-algebras and measure theory in a reasonable way as it can be found in many books. Therefore I often struggle with proving such thing because we have almost nothing what we can use, or it's extremly technical. the literature the lecture is based on is in German

Comment: and thank you very much for your patience and your help

Comment: @hetty I didn't mean to discourage you by my comment. All I wanted to say was it is hard for others to understand how exactly they should answer the question when the definitions are not standard. But good luck with your study of measure theory.

Comment: yes. You are right. I just realized that the definitions are not standard. I wasn't aware of it while posting the question. Next time I will state the definitions here